# Hudson build fails with FATAL: null java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Tags: hudson

I've installed Hudson on Ubuntu and I am using the git plugin.  The git integration and the simple shell script I execute as the build step appear to be working fine, but I get the following error and the build fails:

```
FATAL: null
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.getCulprits(AbstractBuild.java:278)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.getCulprits(AbstractBuild.java:275)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.post(AbstractBuild.java:565)
at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1386)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:145)
```

I have no post-build actions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the same exception, and the reason in my case was an incompatibility when using hudson 2.0.0 and the hudson git plugin 2.0.1. 
Either upgrade your hudson server or uninstall the git plugin and manually install the older git plugin version from http://hudson-ci.org/downloads/plugins/git/2.0.0/.

Comment: I think you're right, I have used a different version of hudson and fixed the problem.